# Efficient way to validate array values

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am reading in certain values of a CSV file into an array, and I want to run some basic validation checks against each value before inserting each row into a MySQL database. I'm wondering how to do this efficiently, with some sort of rules array.

e.g i only want values at certain positions in each row of the CSV

```
$while ($data = fgetcsv....)

$val1 = $data[2];
$val2 = $data[9];
$val3 = $data[11];
```

I want to validate each val - if any of the vals doesn't validate, will abort insert

```
if (ctype_alnum($val1) AND ctype_alnum($val2) AND is_numeric($val3))
```

The above approach starts to look pretty inefficient when dealing with approx 30 values, so I was wondering if a way to improve it by creating an array which stores the desired value position and also the validation rule. Something like the below...

```
$vals = array(
'val1' => array('pos' => 2, 'rule' => 'ctype_alphanum')
)
```

Any pointers on this would be great..!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what for you need `pos` element in array, but for the other part you can look into this. If more complex needed change it accordingly

```
$vals = array(
   'val1' => array(
       'rule' => 'ctype_alnum',
   ),
   'val2' => array(
       'rule' => 'ctype_digit',
   ),
);

function print_out( $val )
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump( $val );
    echo '</pre>';
}

print_out( $vals );

array_walk( $vals, function( &$value, $key ){
    $result          = call_user_func( $value['rule'], $value['value'] );
    $value['result'] = $result;
});

print_out( $vals );
```

**UPDATE**

`$var = fgetcsv(...);` here you get a row from csv.
`$neededRange = array_slice( $var, $x[, $n] );` this way you will get the part you need.
And since I see you only need one rule for all elements, then.

```
array_walk( $array, function( &$value, $key ){
    $value = array(
        'value' => $value,
        'rule'  => 'ctype_alnum',
    );
 });
```

Also updated validation algorithm.

Comment: Thanks. The `pos` refers to the position in the array (csv row) where I will extract the value from for this field.

Comment: Can't you first get an array with values you need to validate and then run code from my example? Seems, that would be easier.

Comment: Yeah - that's the way i do it at the moment, just running through each field one by one, accessing the desired key -> value and adding to an array, but was wondering if there was a way of storing the key/pos info for each field along with the validation rule. Possibly not..

Comment: Is it different element in csv row every time? and how will it know what type of rule to use?

Comment: Within each csv row, there are say 40 values. I want to extract 30 of them by their position in the row. I then need to validate that they are all the data type i expect them to be. The position in the row will be consistent.

Comment: Can't you just array `array_slice` the part you need and then run similar function to what I wrote to change value part, so it would become array and then validate resulting array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26147/discussion-between-eugene-and-bsod99)